# Pandas: lookup values in DataFrame, where source column has multiple members

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF with data and a DF representing a database for querying and returning data. I can't use merge because some rows contain multiple lookups.

Data:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame([[1000, 'Jerry', 'BR1001, BR1003, BR9009','',''], 
                        [1001, 'Buck', 'BR1010, BR1011','',''], 
                        [1002, 'Melanie', 'BR3009','','DPT2002'],
                        [1003, 'Perry','BR4009','',''],
                        [1004, 'Perry2','','DIST1000',''],
                        [1005, 'Eloise','','','DPT9009'],
                        [1005, 'Sharon','','','DPT9009']],
                        columns=['ID', 'Name', 'School Number','District Number','Dept. Number'])
```

Given the `School Number`, I need to be able to pull all associated `District Number`s and `Dept. Number`s. I'd like to just focus on pulling the `District Number`s. The issue is how to iterate over members in a field where there is more than one.

Data to query:

```
df_DB = pd.DataFrame([['DIST1000', 'BR1001', 'DPT9009','Physics'], 
                    ['DIST1000', 'BR1003', 'DPT1010','Biology'],
                    ['DIST1000', 'BR1003', 'DPT1011','Sociology'],
                    ['DIST1000', 'BR1010', 'DPT1012','Philosophy'],
                    ['DIST1000', 'BR1011', 'DPT1013','Pre-K'],
                    ['DIST1000', 'BR1012', 'DPT1014','Geology'],
                    ['DIST1001', 'BR9009', 'DPT2001', 'Math'],
                    ['DIST1001', 'BR3009', 'DPT2002', 'Physics'],
                    ['DIST1001', 'BR9009', 'DPT2003', 'Pre-K'],
                    ['DIST1001', 'BR4009', 'DPT2004', 'Economics']],
                    columns=['District Number', 'School Number', 'Dept. Number','Name'])
```

Ex., Note the first record in the data above, *Jerry*. He has 3 `School Number`s assigned to his record.

Desired output (Ex.):

```
1000, 'Jerry', 'BR1001, BR1003, BR9009','DIST1001, DIST1000','DPT9009, DPT1010, DPT1011, DPT2001, DPT2003'
```

Do I need a function for this? I think I can figure out Department if I can land the District Numbers.

Comment: Did you find `df.explode` searching for a result ? That could be a way to go.

Comment: I did not. Will look into that now. Thank you!

Comment: I think the answer below drops rows if there is no match or maybe if the matching field is blank. Is that posible?

Comment: I was thinking the same when seeing it. So you want to keep all `ID's` regardless of there is a match or no match ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Changing type from string to list.
df_data['School Number'] = df_data['School Number'].apply(lambda x: x.split(", ")) 

# Expanding list into rows, selecting the desired columns from both tables,
# grouping by the ID, and returning the list of district numbers and schools along with the 
# first name per ID (which is a guaranteed 1:1), then we join these values with a comma after turning them into a set (no duplicates).

df_data.explode('School Number')[['ID', 'Name', 'School Number']].merge(df_DB[['School Number', 'District Number']], left_on='School Number', right_on='School Number').groupby('ID').agg({'Name': 'first', 'School Number': lambda x: ', '.join(set(x)), 'District Number': lambda x: ', '.join(set(x))})
```

Output:

```
             Name           School Number     District Number
ID
1000    Jerry  BR1001, BR9009, BR1003  DIST1000, DIST1001
1001     Buck          BR1011, BR1010            DIST1000
1002  Melanie                  BR3009            DIST1001
1003    Perry                  BR4009            DIST1001
```

Or, for a left join:

```
df_data.explode('School Number')[['ID', 'Name', 'School Number']].merge(df_DB[['School Number', 'District Number']], left_on='School Number', right_on='School Number', how='left').groupby('ID').agg({'Name': 'first', 'School Number': lambda x: ', '.join(set(x)), 'District Number': lambda x: ', '.join(set([y for y in x if y == y]))})
```

Output:

```
         Name           School Number     District Number
ID
1000    Jerry  BR1003, BR1001, BR9009  DIST1000, DIST1001
1001     Buck          BR1011, BR1010            DIST1000
1002  Melanie                  BR3009            DIST1001
1003    Perry                  BR4009            DIST1001
1004   Perry2
1005   Eloise
```

Comment: When I run this it doesn't show all records from the data.

Comment: OK -- I think I understand the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Mohammed Ayoub -  Will this drop rows if there is no matches?

Comment: Yes. This will drop rows. You can change the behavior based on the merge function, see where it says left_on and right_on? You can specify how='left' so that values from the left table are kept even if there are no matches, 'right' for right, and 'outer' for all. Please mark the answer as correct if it's satisfied your question. Find the documentation on the function here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: When I add `how='left` I get an error. `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

Comment: Left joins cause errors.

Comment: `left join` with `groupby` cause errors due to missing values, I believe. How can I represent the non-matched rows.